# How can this long list of variables be cleaned up?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Inside of a tkinter loop I have a list of variables that store user inputted text strings. I use the `.get` method in tkinter to assign the tkinter text variables to regular python variables. I then pass these variables to a function and return them. But it's gotten quite messy.

It technically works but I'd like to make it nicer on the eyes. I included `check_inputs()` (which is a file in `checkInputsMaster.py`) to show how the variables are passed and returned to other functions. All other functions are designed like this.

Main:

```
# obtains user inputted variables from GUI and feeds them into all other modules
folderPath,ship,flightNumber,flightDate,testNumber,missionNumber,pilot,tc,ops,missionType,etd,eta,sw,tm,gps,rdr,rtas,rswb,rmwb,lswb,lmwb,slam = check_inputs(folder_path,ship1,flight_number,flight_date,test_number,mission_number,pilot1,tc1,ops1,mission_type,etd1,eta1,sw1,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9)
flightParameters = [folderPath,ship,flightNumber,flightDate,testNumber,missionNumber,pilot,tc,ops,missionType,etd,eta,sw,tm,gps,rdr,rtas,rswb,rmwb,lswb,lmwb,slam]
# test command print(flightParameters)

# main chunk of code that creates paperwork
check_errors(*flightParameters)
logger(*flightParameters)
```

`check_inputs()` function in `checkInputsMaster.py`:

```
def check_inputs(folder_path,ship1,flight_number,flight_date,test_number,mission_number,pilot1,tc1,ops1,mission_type,etd1,eta1,sw1,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9):
    print('--------------------------\nProgram starting.\nGrabbing User Input Variables')
    global folderPath
    global ship
    global flightNumber
    global flightDate
    global testNumber
    global missionNumber
    global pilot
    global tc
    global ops
    global missionType
    global eta
    global etd
    global sw

    global tm
    global gps
    global rdr
    global rtas
    global rswb
    global rmwb
    global lswb
    global lmwb
    global slam


    folderPath=folder_path.get()
    ship=ship1.get()
    flightNumber=flight_number.get()
    flightDate=flight_date.get()
    testNumber=test_number.get()
    missionNumber=mission_number.get()
    pilot=pilot1.get()
    tc=tc1.get()
    ops=ops1.get()
    missionType=mission_type.get()
    etd=etd1.get()
    eta=eta1.get()
    sw=sw1.get()


    tm=var1.get()
    gps=var2.get()
    rdr=var3.get()
    rtas=var4.get()
    rswb=var5.get()
    rmwb=var6.get()
    lswb=var7.get()
    lmwb=var8.get()
    slam=var9.get()

    print('Variables have been grabbed')

    return(folderPath,ship,flightNumber,flightDate,testNumber,missionNumber,pilot,tc,ops,missionType,etd,eta,sw,tm,gps,rdr,rtas,rswb,rmwb,lswb,lmwb,slam)
```

Comment: Can you try having all the variables in a dictionary?

Comment: The common way to avoid global variables (or at least minimize the number of them) is to use containers of some short (like lists and dictionaries), or often better, define a custom class to hold (and update) them.

Comment: Why do you declare them as global and also are passing them in as parameters? That leads to confusing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping your GUI in a class that returns your data as a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), or perhaps as a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) if you're looking for something a bit more flexible. Also, if your GUI has too many elements you may want to consider breaking it into smaller sub-GUIs.

You can also look into [kwargs](https://www.google.com/search?q=kwargs+python) if you have long lists of input variables.

Simple example of a namedtuple class below.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from collections import namedtuple

class SimpleGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('Simple GUI')

        self.var1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var2 = tk.StringVar()

        frame = tk.Frame(self.window)
        frame.grid(sticky='nesw')

        entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.var1)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nesw')

        entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.var2)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nesw')
        
    def get_variables(self):
        Variables = namedtuple('Variables', ['var1', 'var2'])
        return Variables(self.var1.get(), self.var2.get())
```

```py
>>> from simplegui import SimpleGUI
>>> gui = SimpleGUI() # Here I enter 'test1' and 'test2' into the tkinter window
>>> vars = gui.get_variables()
>>> vars
Variables(var1='test 1', var2='test 2')
>>> vars.var1
'test 1'
>>> vars.var2
'test 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed better ways of doing that.  A step in the right direction would be to store all your information in a dictionary instead of a list.  `flightParameters` just has all your data bunched up in a row which works, but a dictionary lets you name all of your data in it instead of having to refer to each item by number.

Next, there is no reason to pass a bunch of variables to your `check_inputs` function like that; especially since you immediately tell the program to use global versions of the variables instead; which is also weird because you return all those variables back.  I would not do any of that and simply store all your `.get`s in to a dictionary that returns back to your main code and is saved as flightParameters.

Example changes to first part:

```
# obtains user inputted variables from GUI and feeds them into all other modules
flightParameters = check_inputs() # this will call check_inputs() and then save what it returns to flightParameters
# test command print(flightParameters)

# main chunk of code that creates paperwork
check_errors(*flightParameters)
logger(*flightParameters)
```

Example changes to second part:

```
def check_inputs():
    print('--------------------------\nProgram starting.\nGrabbing User Input Variables')
    flight_parameters = {} # empty dictionary
    
    flight_parameters['folderPath']=folder_path.get()
    flight_parameters['ship']=ship1.get()
    flight_parameters['flightNumber']=flight_number.get()
    flight_parameters['flightDate']=flight_date.get()
    flight_parameters['testNumber']=test_number.get()
    flight_parameters['missionNumber']=mission_number.get()
    flight_parameters['pilot']=pilot1.get()
    flight_parameters['tc']=tc1.get()
    flight_parameters['ops']=ops1.get()
    flight_parameters['missionType']=mission_type.get()
    flight_parameters['etd']=etd1.get()
    flight_parameters['eta']=eta1.get()
    flight_parameters['sw']=sw1.get()

    flight_parameters['tm']=var1.get()
    flight_parameters['gps']=var2.get()
    flight_parameters['rdr']=var3.get()
    flight_parameters['rtas']=var4.get()
    flight_parameters['rswb']=var5.get()
    flight_parameters['rmwb']=var6.get()
    flight_parameters['lswb']=var7.get()
    flight_parameters['lmwb']=var8.get()
    flight_parameters['slam']=var9.get()

    print('Variables have been grabbed')

    return flight_parameter # return the now-filled dictionary
```

If you do it this way, there really is a lot less craziness in there.  You will have to access your data like this:

```
flightParameters['flightNumber']
```

instead of doing this:

```
flightParameters[2]
```

What you may want to consider as well is keeping all your `StringVar`s in a dictionary as well.  You could then replace check_inputs with something like this:

```
def check_inputs():
    print('--------------------------\nProgram starting.\nGrabbing User Input Variables')
    flight_parameters = {}
    for i in my_string_vars:
        flight_parameters[i] = my_string_vars[i].get()
    print('Variables have been grabbed')
    return(flight_parameters)
```

Comment: When using this approach, the main chunk of code imports the `checkInputs` function. When I tried to run the function in the main chunk of code, the function that I call doesn't know what the StringVar variables are/have them defined.

How can these variables carry over into different files?

Comment: You can import variables just like you would import functions or classes.  Python is good like that; it treats them all the same.  I would not recommend importing over dozens of variables though as that would be messy.  Put them all in a list, set or dictionary and just import that.  Or, you could set them all up as variables in a class and import that class.

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely use a `dataclass` for this. Here are my reasons why:

1. You can assign all the variables with the proper order, instead of one name at a time
2. You are basically creating the python equivalent of a `typedef` so, it's not going to let you just make up names, misspell things, etc. Only exactly what you define is allowed.
3. You don't have to `key` the names (ex: `myDC['myVar']`) you can refer to them like properties (ex: `myDC.myVar`)
4. You can default the values of a `dataclass` and only overwrite the things that need to change.
5. Values are strict typed
6. Easily converted to a dict if necessary
7. This actually negates any need for a function in the first place
8. You can divide the data into meaningful groups and then recombine it all into a "super group" (example below)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class BaseSpecs:
    folderPath   :str = ''
    ship         :str = ''
    flightNumber :str = ''
    flightDate   :str = ''
    testNumber   :str = ''


@dataclass
class MissionSpecs:
    missionNumber :str = ''
    pilot         :str = ''
    tc            :str = ''
    ops           :str = ''
    missionType   :str = ''
    eta           :str = ''
    etd           :str = ''
    sw            :str = ''
    

@dataclass
class FlightSpecs:
    tm   :str = ''
    gps  :str = ''
    rdr  :str = ''
    rtas :str = ''
    rswb :str = ''
    rmwb :str = ''
    lswb :str = ''
    lmwb :str = ''
    slam :str = ''
    
    
@dataclass            #order is last to first
class FlightParameters(FlightSpecs, MissionSpecs, BaseSpecs):
    pass


#the order is taken advantage of here.
#no need to specifically state every property name
flightParams = FlightParameters(
    folder_path.get(),
    ship1.get(),
    flight_number.get(),
    flight_date.get(),
    test_number.get(),
    mission_number.get(),
    pilot1.get(),
    tc1.get(),
    ops1.get(),
    mission_type.get(),
    etd1.get(),
    eta1.get(),
    sw1.get(),
    var1.get(),
    var2.get(),
    var3.get(),
    var4.get(),
    var5.get(),
    var6.get(),
    var7.get(),
    var8.get(),
    var9.get(),
)

#treated like a property instead of a key
print(flightParams.folderPath)

#easily converted to dict
flightParamsDict = asdict(flightParams)
```

Alternately, due to how the above is structured, you could also do it as below.

```
base = BaseSpecs(
    folder_path.get(),
    ship1.get(),
    flight_number.get(),
    flight_date.get(),
    test_number.get(),
)

mission = MissionSpecs(
    mission_number.get(),
    pilot1.get(),
    tc1.get(),
    ops1.get(),
    mission_type.get(),
    etd1.get(),
    eta1.get(),
    sw1.get(),
)

flight = FlightSpecs(
    var1.get(),
    var2.get(),
    var3.get(),
    var4.get(),
    var5.get(),
    var6.get(),
    var7.get(),
    var8.get(),
    var9.get(),
)

flightParams = FlightParameters(**asdict(base), **asdict(mission), **asdict(flight))
```